# Add a chromium link to the Plasma desktop

Tags: kubuntu, kde, chromium

I'm running Kubuntu and would like to add a link onto the desktop that opens a specific url in Chromium.

I tried creating a bookmark and dragging that onto the desktop, with no success. I also went through the widgets one could add but found nothing that sounded useful, besides an application launcher and a website viewer. Certainly there must be a way to do this, right?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Right-click on the desktop, click "Unlock widgets" (unless they are already unlocked), right-click again and click "Add widgets." Click and drag the "Folder View" widget to the desktop. Right-click on the widget and go to Create New > Link to application. Type the name of the link in the box and use the"Application" tab to set the command. Here's an example command:

chromium "https://www.example.com"

Comment: Pretty complicated, but works, if you replace *chromium* with *chromium-browser*. Major downside is that I have to literally create a file in the Desktop. That means that if I wanted to have different desktop links in different activities, well, I cant, unless I create folder views to different folders in each activity, which is way overboard.